# PHPmailer attachment not included sometimes

Tags: php, phpmailer

I use PHPmailer to send the mails.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->From      = 'some address';
$mail->FromName  = 'some name';
$mail->Subject   = 'some subject';
$mail->Body      = $bodytext;
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->AddAddress('some email');

// FILES
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) 
{
    $filedata['name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];

    $path = "somepath";     
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $path);
    {    
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT...");
        $stmt->execute($filedata);

        $mail->AddAttachment( $path, $filedata['name']);
    }
}

$mail->Send();
```

The problem is, **sometimes** (not always) the attachment is not included in the email, but **always** uploaded to the server and added to DB.

What is the problem? Probably, the move_uploaded_file hasn't finished uploading at the moment of addAttachment?

Comment: what !!! move the file and sending mail ???. It's a wrong approach.  Move file first and add then store it to DB or array and attach them with proper looping method

Comment: I'm adding to the server and DB, and adding attachment in 1 loop. Why is it wrong?

Comment: then `move_uploaded_file` does here ?? Read https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial#file-attachments

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Are you able to explain in the normal way, so I could understand you?

Comment: if these files are uploaded already, then just get the path from DB and add it to `$mail->AddAttachment` in foreach loop. Upload files first and then do attaching

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I did the same, isn't it? The variable `$path` is the path of the attachment, written in DB also.

Comment: You're not checking the result of `move_uploaded_file`, so you're not seeing when it fails. Look at the [multiple file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps) for how to do this correctly.

Comment: @Synchro The point is, the file is uploaded, but not included in attachment. So, file upload didn't fail.

Comment: You can't tell because you're not checking the results of `move_uploaded_file` nor `addAttachment`, you're just assuming they work.

Comment: @Synchro I can, because I see the file in the DB and in the server, but attachment is empty. I have an assumption, that the move_uploaded_file hasn't finished uploading at the moment of AddAttachment, but how can I wait when it finishes?

Comment: No, *you can't tell* because *you're not checking*. The `$_FILES` array may be populated (and that's all that's going into your database) but that doesn't tell you if `move_uploaded_file` works, and that's all you're seeing. A `$_FILES` entry will exist but be empty if the file exceeds the size specified in the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` value in your form, or the equivalent value in your php.ini. You're drawing the wrong conclusion from the fact that data is getting into your DB. `move_uploaded_file` and `addAttachment` are both synchronous, so that's not the issue.

Comment: @Synchro As I said, I check the file in the server, it's moved successfully and not empty!

Comment: Sigh. Your **code** is not checking it, and that's what matters.

Comment: How do you suggest to modify my code, so the attachments will always be included? Please, add in Answer form.

Comment: @Synchro How do you suggest to modify my code, so the attachments will always be included? Please, add in Answer form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the file was uploaded correctly, that it's not empty, and that PHPMailer could load it.

Paraphrasing [the PHPMailer example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps):

```
try {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if ((int)$_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i] === 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Zero length file; may exceed allowed size.');
        }
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i]));
        $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadfile)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to move file $filename to $uploadfile");
        }
        if (!$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to attach file $filename");
        }
        //Everything is ok, so do whatever else you need to do, like store the record in the DB
    }
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
    echo 'File upload failed:', htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: What would it give, in comparison with my solution? Just to remember, my problem is the attachment not included while the file uploaded.

Comment: Run the code and it will tell you? I can't compare it because you don't *have* a solution.

Comment: How am I supposed to be able to tell that? I'm not the one running your code. Run it and see for yourself.

Comment: You see my code and you modified it. Do you really know what you did?

Comment: Yes I added checking so that **you** could see what happens when **you** run it. When you run it and it it fails to add an attachment, it will tell you **why** it failed, which is what your code doesn't do. I'm not about to reproduce your entire deployment stack just to show you that a bit of code does what it says.

Comment: so, your code will help to understand what happens, not solves the problem